# Using Excel with VLOOKUP but then match value and return contents of adjacent cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet as sample spreadsheet.

[image: Data Sample]

I need to use `VLOOKUP` to reference the id, then find Codes across several columns and return the mark from the adjacent column, any help would be great.

Eg - What mark was achieved for AF for everyone, even though AF appears in different columns.
Column A = ID
Columns B, D, F and G could contain codes
When code is found I need to return the value in the column to the right of the matched code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `INDEX`, `MATCH`, and `OFFSET` to achieve what you want. To find what ID `414` marked for code `AF`, assuming your sample table is in range A1:J6, you can use

```
=INDEX(OFFSET($A$1:$J$1,MATCH(414,$A$2:$A$6,0),0),MATCH("AF",OFFSET($A$1:$J$1,MATCH(414,$A$2:$A$6,0),0),0)+1)
```

Breaking this down, `OFFSET($A$1:$J$1,MATCH(414,$A$2:$A$6,0),0)`, which appears twice in the formula, represents the row you want to look in. `MATCH("AF",...,0)` returns the column number where `AF` is found in that row. Adding 1 to this gives the column number to the right `AF`. `INDEX(...,MATCH("AF",...,0)+1)` returns the value from that column.